# flash messages not displaying rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display a flash message on a redirect but am having some trouble getting them to display.

What I want to happen is after an email is saved we display a message. Below are a few different ways I've attempted to do this.

Controller setup - I tried setting the flash the two different way's showed in the method below. The puts statement is being hit.

```
  def subscriber_email_landing_page
    email = Email.create(email: subscriber_email_params[:email], subscriber_type: 'mtb-landing-page')

    if email.save
      puts 'hit flash'
      flash[:notice] = "Post has been saved successfully."
      redirect_to mountain_bike_path, flash: { notice: 'hey'}
    end
  end
```

Different way's I've tried to display the flash in the view:

```
  <%= flash[:notice] %>

  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "flash #{key}" %>
  <% end %>

  <% if !flash.empty? %>
    <% puts 'flash working' %>
    <p>hey how are ya</p>
  <% end %>
```

I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing. Can someone lend some seasoned rails advice?

Comment: Is 'hey how are ya' displayed?

Comment: Try this `redirect_to mountain_bike_path, notice: 'hey'`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I currently have flash setup in my Rails application

In app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

      # bootstrap flash notifications
      def flash_class(level)
        case level
          when 'notice' then "alert alert-info"
          when 'success' then "alert alert-success"
          when 'error' then "alert alert-danger"
          when 'alert' then "alert alert-warning"
        end
      end

    end
```

in app/views/shared/_flash.html.erb

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="<%= flash_class(key) %>">
            <%= value %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

example of calling flash in a controller

```
def require_user_signin
  unless current_user
    # stores url in the session that the user was trying to go to before being redirected
    session[:intended_url] = request.url
    redirect_to new_session_url 
    flash[:error] = "please sign in first!"
  end    
end
```

or

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)   
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id # creates session to login user
    flash[:success] = "Hi #{@user.first_name.capitalize}, thanks for creating an account!"
    redirect_to user_url(@user.id)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

in a view

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/flash' %>
  <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @job %>
```

might want to check this out too for a reference https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#sec-the_flash

Comment: try copying how I have it setup and see if that works.  I updated the answer to show a create action.  can you add a flash message when you create a user and see if that works to rule out anything with the subscriber_email_landing_page function?